# PyTables Not Writing Fast Enough

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, cython, pytables

I am currently having trouble trying to get PyTables to write data to itself faster. Let me explain my current scenario.

Right now I have data that comes in via multicasts, a high rate of data. I have a parser and a data structure that hashes the data into dictionaries that are sent off to be stored in PyTables.

I have a thread that accepts this dictionary with its key being and id and its value being an array of instances of data that apply to the id. The thread iterates over the key value pairs and adds the data to a table that corresponds to the id.

Here is my current implementation, so far the array of dictionaries acts as buffer that increases linearly over time. This is my obvious problem. The code shows the constant loop that the writer thread makes to write data.

```
def acceptDict():
    while True:
        while not dicts.empty():
            lock.acquire()
            dictInst = dicts.get()
            print dicts.qsize()
            for instrument, dataArray in dictInst.iteritems():
                if instrument in tableExists:
                    tableD = openFi.getNode("/t" + str(instrument), "direct")
                else:
                    tableExists[instrument] = 1
                    group = openFi.createGroup("/", "t" + str(instrument), str(instrument))
                    tableD = openFi.createTable(group, "direct", Tick, "direct")
                for i in dataArray:
                    tableD.row['timestamp'] = i[0]
                    tableD.row['side'] = i[1]
                    tableD.row['level'] = i[2]
                    tableD.row['price'] = i[3]
                    tableD.row['quant'] = i[4]
                    tableD.row['orders'] = i[5]
                    tableD.row.append()
                tableD.flush()
            lock.release()
```

Comment: Have you profiled this function to find out if any of the specific function calls you are making is the prime offender? If for example it is the ``flush`` call this might point to a different solution compared to the ``createTable`` call.